# Tilting web browser on windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

i'm working on a windows phone 7 emulator. I have a web browser which navigates to local host. So my problem i faced was that when i tilt the windows phone 7 emulator 90% right, the screen doesn't. Could there be any advice on how to do so?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

namespace DSP
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ContentPanel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Loading website.  This might take a few seconds...");
            webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://localhost/Liweiyi_fyp_082648y/homepage.html", UriKind.Absolute));
        }

        private void webBrowser1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your SupportedOrientations is PortraitOrLandscape in your xaml.

Also check your emulator isn't orientation locked due to hardware keybaord emulation. Restart it if you're not sure how to fix that.

Comment: For the sake of simplicity, I glossed over the detail of using PAUSE and PGUP/DN because it can be fiddly. If you decide to go via this route, it helps if you have a textbox (in any app) with focus when using those keys - the state will be remembered while you keep the emulator open and switch between apps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for [how to handle orientation changes on the phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769553(v=vs.92).aspx)?

You're looking to change the following in the .xaml for the appropriate page - most likely MainPage.xaml:

[image]

Change the highlighted line to read

```
SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape"
```

And in case that wasn't enough information, here's [a helpful blogpost](http://www.eugenedotnet.com/2010/11/w03-page-orientation-in-windows-phone-7/).

Comment: As mentioned by @Mick N, there's issues that arise with the display/orientation at times when in "hardware keyboard mode", either from hitting the Pause/Break key or Page Up/Page Down - if you're looking to test orientation I'd recommend at least one runthrough without using hardware keyboard in the emulator.